# Babel cannot find module '@babel/preset-presets-env'

Tags: javascript, babeljs, node-modules, npm-install

I installed **Babel** via **NPM Install** to make my Javascript code viewable for all Browsers, but I get an **Error** when I run this command: `node_modules/.bin/babel before.js -o after.js`

It tells me it `cannot find the module '@babel/preset-presets-env`

**Error Output:**

```
*Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-presets-env'* from 'C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19'
    at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:90:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePreset (C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:58:10)
    at loadPreset (C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:77:20)
    at createDescriptor (C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50    
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\Firebase Firestore Tutorial\javascript 1\lesson 19\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:47:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Comment: Have you installed this package too? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-env

Comment: Yes I have, still doesnt work

Comment: I Fixed it!I deleted my Project and started fresh with installing babel and now it runs Smooth. Thanks anyway for your time! :D

Answer (score 3):

**I have same issue but got solution with:**

### Previously webpack code was:

```
// comple Babel Code with given rules
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/presets-env',
                            '@babel/presets-react'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

### Replace with:

```
// comple Babel Code with given rules
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/
                }
            ]
        }
```

After making this change code start working...!

:-)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my Project and started fresh with installing babel and now it runs Smooth. :D